# How to retrieve data from firebase from multiple attributes

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am Firebase newbie. I want to retrieve data which is 2016 year and month is february and its location. I using android studio.

How can I solve this problem?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your question shows [no attempt](//idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) of solving the problem. If you have made an attempt, you should edit our question to detail exactly what you did, researched for, and point to any links that were helpful but that did not answer your question. If you’ve tried to code a solution, that should be added in an edit. Your attempts should be turned into a [MCVE](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so it is clear to read and understand. Also read the [Stack Overflow question checklist](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648)

Comment: It looks like you're trying to filter on two property. The Firebase Realtime Database can only order/query on a single property. Luckily you can combine your two properties into one, and filter on that: `"YEAR_MONTH": "201502"`. Also see: Firebase Database queries can only order/filter on a single property. In many cases it is possible to combine the values you want to filter on into a single (synthetic) property. For an example of this and other approaches, see my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26700924/query-based-on-multiple-where-clauses-in-firebase